# Query to send users message within a crm

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I need help understanding the logic of a query I`m trying to write. I want the employees to be able to message other employees. I need the employee to see the list of all employees he can send messages to.

**notifications table**

```
id | time | fromUser_id | fromEmployee_id | fromEmployee_fname | fromEmployee_lname |to_Userid | message | employee_id
```

**users table**

```
id | username | email | password | employee |
```

**employees table**

```
id | employee_id | notifications_id | users_id | first_name | last_name | username
```

**So far this is what I have in the select tag:**

```
<select  id='toEmployee' class='form-control formBlock' name='toUser_id' value='' type='text' class='form-control formBlock'>
                 <option value="">To...</option>
                   <?php
    $employeesQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employees");
    while ($employee = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $employeesQuery)) {
        ?>
  <option value="<?php ;?>"><?php echo $employee['first_name'] ;?> <?php echo $employee['last_name'] ;?></option>
    <?php } ;?>
</select>
```

I know it's not the correct query but I have hard time understanding the logic to make it work.

Comment: How (in English rather than database syntax) do you determine "the list of employees he can send messages to"? Is it that the "Notifications" table has a record with that "from" and "to" Employee? Or something else?

Comment: Fast guess: you're listing the "first_name - last_name" of each employee in the <options> of your <select>. You need to add, as a value, the PRIMARY KEY that uniquely identifies them. So: `<?php echo $employee['employee_id'] ;?>` might be a good guess. [Looks strange that your employees table has one `id` and one `employee_id`. Seems redundant.]